# Python json add multiple keys and iterate

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am looking to convert a dataframe to json, this is the code I currently have:

```
my_frame = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Age':[30, 31], 
     'Eye':['blue', 'brown'], 
     'Gender': ['male', 'female']})
my_frame = my_frame.to_json(orient='records')
my_frame
```

Result:

```
'[{"Age":30,"Eye":"blue","Gender":"male"},{"Age":31,"Eye":"brown","Gender":"female"}]'
```

I want to **add keys** to the json object and add the key **info** over the entire data that was converted from the dataframe.

```
add_keys = {'id': 101,
    'loc': 'NY',
}
add_keys['info'] = my_frame
add_keys
```

Result:

```
{'id': 101,
 'info': '[{"Age":30,"Eye":"blue","Gender":"male"},
{"Age":31,"Eye":"brown","Gender":"female"}]',
 'loc': 'NY'}
```

I want to print each of the two records within info, however when I run this iterative code it outputs each character of the string rather than the entire record. I believe this may be an issue from how I am **adding the keys**.

```
for item in add_keys['info']:
    print(item)
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should be putting the original dataframe into `add_keys['info']`, not the JSON representation.

Comment: It is because your list is being treated as string. Convert it and it will be fixed

Comment: `my_frame` is a string, you need to convert it, something like this: `add_keys['info'] = json.loads(my_frame)`

Comment: Have a look into answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is better to use [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) inbuilt functionality here. So, this is what you need: `add_keys['info'] = my_frame.T.to_dict().values()`

Here is the **whole code**:

```
>>> my_frame = pd.DataFrame(
...     {'Age':[30, 31],
...      'Eye':['blue', 'brown'],
...      'Gender': ['male', 'female']})
>>> my_frame
   Age    Eye  Gender
0   30   blue    male
1   31  brown  female
>>> add_keys = {'id': 101,
...     'loc': 'NY',
... }
>>> add_keys
{'loc': 'NY', 'id': 101}
>>> add_keys['info'] = my_frame.T.to_dict().values()
>>> add_keys
{'info': [{'Gender': 'male', 'Age': 30L, 'Eye': 'blue'}, {'Gender': 'female', 'Age': 31L, 'Eye': 'brown'}], 'loc': 'NY', 'id': 101}
>>> for item in add_keys['info']:
...     print(item)
...
{'Gender': 'male', 'Age': 30L, 'Eye': 'blue'}
{'Gender': 'female', 'Age': 31L, 'Eye': 'brown'}
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using `to_json()`, pandas is generating a string containing the JSON representation of the dataframe.

If you want to retain the structure of your records in order to manipulate them, use

```
my_frame = my_frame.to_dict(orient='records')
```

Then after adding keys, if you want to serialize your data, you can do

```
json.dumps(add_keys)
```